# Flutter: extend a class by having to implement a method

Tags: dart, flutter, overriding, extends

Since I have two similar classes, but with little differences in only one function, I want to create a base class that they will extend, but that will also force them to implement that specific function. To better explain this:

```
class A {
void print() {print "hello";}
void func (){}
}

class B extends A {
@override func(){
 //TODO
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use an abstract base class, that is the parent of both classes

```
abstract class Base {
  void func();
}

class A extends Base{

  @override
  void func() {

   }

}

class B extends Base {
  @override
  void func() {

  }

}
```

Comment: I did a great mistake. I was writing "void func(){}"  instead of "void func();" in the Base class, so the A class didn't complain about missing implementation.  Thanks!